# How to achieve parallax effect in ios8 objective c

Tags: objective-c, parallax

I have a google map that is a `gmsmapview` covering half screen. And below that I have collection view. I need to have scrolling effect not only for the collection view but also for the google map.

How can I use parallax in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching over to `MapKit` for your map, there are several already created solutions that you could easily drop right into your project.

Check out these two controls: [SLParallaxController](https://github.com/StefanLage/SLParallaxController) and [LocationPickerView](https://github.com/mstrchrstphr/LocationPickerView)